# Как сделать разную цену за доставку, в зависимости от адреса?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Такова проблема что разрабатываю сайт пиццерии, и необходимо сделать так, чтобы доставка меняла свою стоимость в зависимости от **адреса**.

Условно город поделен на две части, зеленую и красную, если пользователь покупает с **зеленой** зоны, то доставка одной цены, если с **красной** зоны, то другой

Подскажите как такое реализовать на woocommerce? Прошурашал уже весь интернет с даным вопросом

**Вариант с zip code не подходит**

Comment: Advanced Shipment Tracking for WooCommerce думаю подойдет

Comment: К сожалению, не подходит

Comment: В вопросе содержится ответ - тебе нужно создать свои зоны доставки. Также может помочь https://misha.agency/woocommerce/sozdanie-plagina-dostavki.html